# Can't create any new project in MS VS 2010/2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, new-project

I can't create a new project of any kind in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, although for a very long time I could.
It shows a "Couldn't create new project" error.
I thought it was a MS VS 2010 issue and downloaded and installed MS VS 2012.
Then, as it ran into compatibility issues, I downloaded and installed MS VS ServicePack 1.
MS VS 2012 encountered the same problem when I tried creating a new project.
After that, I uninstalled and re-installed both the SP and MS VS 2012 a few times.
I tried running all of them as administartor, but this didn't help.
I still can open previously created projects and change the code in them, but this feels stupid.

PS
I'm under Win 7 64-bit Ultimate Edition.

PPS
I have a strong feeling that I've inadvertently deleted something really criticall for the correct creation of new projects while freeing up disk space.
If I did indeed, I'll be ever-watchfull again, but first I have to solve this problem.

PPPS
Please don't recommend re-installing Windows - it's too much of a bother.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to search the error code it gives you, in google. You will most likely find some solution.

If there is no error code, or you can't find the code/an answer after searching, I think you should re-install it. Most issues are solved that way because there is a corrupted file that prevents applications from behaving normally.

Hope I helped!

Comment: re-install what in particular? I tried re-installing MS VS 2012 and MS VS SP 1, and it didn't help. I'm thinking about re-installing MS VS 2010 as well, but it's tiresome)

Comment: Does it give an error code or a specific error? If so, then what is it?

Comment: none that I've seen; it just says "Couldn't create project" in the left bottom corner.